# Python: jaccard similartity between two networks?

Tags: python, networkx, similarity

I have `2` *large* networks `G` and `G1` generated with the `networkx` package. I want to compute the *jaccard similarity* index between all the nodes.

One possible way is the following:

```
def returnJaccardNetworks(G, G1):
    tmp =   list(G.nodes())
    tmp1 =  list(G1.nodes())
    tmp2 =  np.unique([tmp, tmp1]) ### Find nodes in the networks
    jc = []
    for i in tmp2:
    ## if the node i is in G and in G1 compute 
    ## the similarity between the lists of the ajacent nodes
    ## otherwise append 0
        if (i in G) and (i in G1):  
            k1 = list(G[i]) ## adjacent nodes of i in the network G     
            k2 = list(G1[i]) ## adjacent nodes of i in the network G1 
            ### Start Jaccard Similarity
            intersect = list(set(k1) & set(k2))
            n = len(intersect)
            jc.append(n / float(len(k1) + len(k2) - n))
            ### End Jaccard Similariy
        else:
            jc.append(0)
    return jc
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way. I have noticed that there is a function in the package called `jaccard_coefficient` but I am not sure how it works.

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_prediction.jaccard_coefficient.html

Comment: Based on the link you provided it seems, jacard_coefficient(X,list of tuples of all 2 pairings) should work. where X is G and G' together

Comment: @Bayko thanks but how should I write the code?

Comment: @Bayko That was my first instinct, too, but this approach won't work here as OP needs to preserve the identity of nodes across networks but has a different connectivity in each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation is pretty damn efficient (albeit not pretty, IMO). I can shave off 15% execution time on my machine with this version:

```
def get_jaccard_coefficients(G, H):
    for v in G:
        if v in H:
            n = set(G[v]) # neighbors of v in G
            m = set(H[v]) # neighbors of v in H
            length_intersection = len(n & m)
            length_union = len(n) + len(m) - length_intersection
            yield v, float(length_intersection) / length_union
        else:
            yield v, 0. # should really yield v, None as measure is not defined for these nodes
```

This other version is much more compact and easier to maintain at the cost of a 30% *increase* in execution time:

```
def get_jaccard_coefficients(G, H):
    for v in set(G.nodes) & set(H.nodes): # i.e. the intersection
        n = set(G[v]) # neighbors of v in G
        m = set(H[v]) # neighbors of v in H
        yield v, len(n & m) / float(len(n | m))
```

Comment: As you only considered the nodes in G, and check if they are in H, it seems not to be correct as you dont consider the nodes in H not available in G. So the two first lines of the function needs to be

      def get_jaccard_coefficients(G, H):
           allnodes=list(set(list(G)+list(H)))
    for v in allnodes:
     if (v in H) and (v in G):